# Enable IE8 Add-on Programmatically

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer-8, wix, toolbar, ieaddon

I created a toolbar using Add-In Express for Internet Explorer and it installs fine, I'm using Wix.  The only issue I'm having is I want to enable it after it installs.  For some reason its disabled after it installs.  If I go into Tools > Manage add-ons > Toolbars and Extensions, I see it in the list and I can enable it but I want to do this programmatically.  It's IE8 on Windows XP and Windows 7.  I tried Google'n it but with no success.  I'm looking for anything that can do it: PowerShell, Registry Keys, .NET program, ANYTHING!  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding or updating the following registry value,

**Entry location:** HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\

**Value Name:** Enable Browser Extensions

**Value Type:** REG_SZ (String Value)

**Value:** yes

The value is **yes**.